# DAX How to return Nth selected item

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to find the Nth selected item from a list of text values that are used in a filter.  I cannot find a good solution that will do this.  Below is what I currently have (in DAX Studio)

```
//First get all of the Selected Scenarios and then Rank them based on alphabetical names
//Then filter the Rank to the specific one that I want

Define
var Scenarios = 
Filter(
    AddColumns(ALLSELECTED('Financial All Scenarios'[Scenario]),
    "Rank", RANKX(
        ALLSELECTED('Financial All Scenarios'[Scenario]), 
        'Financial All Scenarios'[Scenario], 
        , 
        ASC
    )
), 
[Rank] = 2)

//Return just the Scenario value for the row that is returned above.
EVALUATE(

MinX(Scenarios, [Scenario])
//Scenarios
)
```

The above gives me the error of the expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression.

I'm note sure why or of another way to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this below measure will give you the expected output-

```
nth_scenario = 

MAXX(
    TOPN(
        2,
        ALLSELECTED('Financial All Scenarios'),        
        'Financial All Scenarios'[Scenario], 
        ASC
    ),
    'Financial All Scenarios'[Scenario]
)
```

Comment: The one thing that I changed to get this to work in my case was changing ALLSELECTED('Financial All Scenarios') to ALLSELECTED('Financial All Scenarios'[Scenario]) because this is actually a fact table, so it has duplicate values in it, putting the AllSelected against the column instead of the whole table made it work as expected.  Thanks.

Comment: nice to see it helped :)